# Are the elements of an array saved continuously in memory?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, memory

I am following a programming paradigm tutorial and doing some memory related exercises. I just extracted two questions (please forget about what the codes look like, sorry it is bad code but I just want to learn the pointer stuff from it). The original codes make lsearch as generic as possible so it uses all pointers.

1. I have a question about accessing an element of an array:

   When we access the fourth element of array `a[]`, we use `*(a+3)`;
   When we access the 3rd element of string array `char * names[]`, we use `*(char**)((char*)names+sizeof(char*)*2)`.
   Do we assume the elements of an array are saved continuously in the memory?
2. Question 2 about accessing string array element: why do we need to add `(char*)` in front of `names` (the base address), I tried not to add `(char*)` and the codes crashed with segmentation fault error. I printed the size of `(char*)`, it is 8, while `sizeof(names)` is 32. Why do we need `(char*)` here? I really think the address is 32 bits and if we cast it into 8 bits, the computer should have trouble finding the element it points to. 
   Thank you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<typeinfo>
int main()
{
        int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        std::cout << *(a+3) << std::endl;


        char* names[4] = {"James", "Dustin", "Rich", "Ed"};
        std::cout << *(char**)((char*)names+2*sizeof(char*)) << std::endl;
        //std::cout << sizeof(names) << " " << sizeof(char*) << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the original codes from stanford 107.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int StrCmp(void* vp1, void* vp2)
{
        char *s1 = *(char**)vp1;
        char *s2 = *(char**)vp2;
        if(strcmp(s1,s2)==0){
                return 0;
        }
        return 1;
}

char ** lsearch(void *key, void* base, int size, int elemSize, int (*cmpFn)(void *, void *))
{
        for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
                char* addr = (char*) base + elemSize *i;
                if (cmpFn(key, addr)==0) return (char**)addr;
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main()
{
        char *notes[] = {"Ab", "F#", "B", "Gb", "D"};
        char* favorStr = "F#";
        char ** found = lsearch(&favorStr,notes,5,sizeof(char*),StrCmp);
        if(found!=NULL) cout << *(char**)found << endl;
        else cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not bits (and your pointers are apparently 64 bits wide).

Comment: This question shows very little prior research, and some of it is wrong. Checking the standards will answer your question about contiguity. Checking some (better) tutorials on arrays and/or pointers will rid you of mystifying constructs like `*(char**)((char*)names+2*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: Also, if you want to use C++, you should probably avoid using old C-style strings. Not that they are as difficult as your post claims, but why live in the past? With modern C++ features you need not worry, at all, about whether things are contiguous, how wide a pointer is, etc.

Comment: That is no C code. And very bad C++ code.

Comment: @underscore_d: Just to state that clear: One would not write it in C that way either actually. And, no that are not "old C-style strings", but that is the way C works. Nothing "old about it". Both languages have their use-cases and should not be regarded "old style". C++ is not much less "past" than C actually.

Comment: Personally I'm fully aware that the syntax is wrong for either language and that C is great in appropriate cases. But this is about the OP, not me, and the OP seems to want to use C++, so I was pointing out where it offers advantages in these cases, especially to someone who very easily gets confused by pointers/arrays.

Comment: OP, how about, instead of constantly making minor edits to a post containing a terrible example that you might have just copied and pasted from a terrible tutorial, you actually engage with the responses to it?

Comment: 1. Yes. Although the correct term is Contiguous. The standards insist on that. 2. Read a book. Stroustrup is excellent.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.3.4 Arrays)

> 1...An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set 
>   of N subobjects of type T.

Applying to the array definition from your post it means only that four pointers (the elements of the array) to string literals are allocated in contiguous extent of memory. This extent of memory does not include the string literals themselves.

In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. When they are used as initializers like this

```
char* names[4] = {"James", "Dustin", "Rich", "Ed"};
```

then they are implicitly converted to pointers of type `const char *` that point to the first elements of the arrays.

So it would be better to define the array like

```
const char* names[4] = {"James", "Dustin", "Rich", "Ed"};
```

If you want to output the third element of the array (take into account that it is a pointer) then you have to write

```
std::cout << ( const void * ) ( names + 2 ) << std::endl;
```

If you want to output the string literal that is pointed to by this element you should write simply

```
std::cout << *( names + 2 ) << std::endl;
```

As for expression

```
*(char**)((char*)names+2*sizeof(char*))
```

then subexpression `(char*)names` reinterprets the array of type  `char *[4] like an array pf type`char [4 * sizeof( char * )]. So expression

```
(char*)names+2*sizeof(char*)
```

yields the same value as expression

```
( names + 2 )
```

For example statements

```
std::cout << ( const void * )( names + 2 ) << std::endl;
```

and

```
std::cout << ( void * )( (char*)names + 2*sizeof(char*) ) << std::endl;
```

will produce the same output

I think if to run this demonstrative program it will be more clear

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const char* names[4] = {"James", "Dustin", "Rich", "Ed"};

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) 
    {        
        std::cout << ( const void * )( names + i ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) 
    {        
        std::cout << ( const void * )*( names + i ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) 
    {        
        std::cout << ( const void * )( ( char * )names + i * sizeof( char * ) ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) 
    {        
        std::cout << ( const void * )*( ( const char ** )( ( const char * )names + i * sizeof( char * ) ) ) << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
0x7fffc0f639f0
0x7fffc0f639f8
0x7fffc0f63a00
0x7fffc0f63a08

0x40d884
0x40d88a
0x40d891
0x40d896

0x7fffc0f639f0
0x7fffc0f639f8
0x7fffc0f63a00
0x7fffc0f63a08

0x40d884
0x40d88a
0x40d891
0x40d896
```

In this program expressions `( names + 0 )`, `( names + 1 )`, `( names + 2 )`, `( names + 3 )` are addresses of correspondingly elements of array names with indices `0, 1, 2, 3`.
Expressions `*( names + 0 )`, `*( names + 1 )`, `*( names + 2 )`, `*( names + 3 )` are the values stored in this elements.

Expressions `( char * )names + i * sizeof( char * )` where i in the range `0-3`
are the same addresses of the array elements. And  expressions 
*( ( const char ** )( ( const char * )names + i * sizeof( char * ) ) ) give the same values of the elements of the array.

Comment: Thank you! I tried std::cout << names+2 << std::endl; It actually gives the same result as std::cout << ( const void * ) ( names + 2 ) << std::endl;

Comment: @daydayup I am sorry. I made a typo. See my updated post.:)

Comment: Thank you @VladfromMoscow! Can I ask , in std::cout << (char*)names+2*sizeof(char*) << std::endl; , why we need to add (char*) before names? I just think names should be of type char* by default because we defined char* names[4] already.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @daydayup Using casting (char *)names interprets the memory extent as a character array. To find the position where the pointer to the third string literal is stored  you have to add to the address of the extent the value equal to 2 * sizeof( char * )

Comment: Thank you @VladfromMoscow. But why, in  int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        std::cout << *(a+3) << std::endl; , we don't need to write *((int)a+3) ? I  am just still confused about when do we need to cast? I thought we use cast only when we need to convert data types

Comment: @daydayup The name of the array is implicitly converted to type int *. Expression a + 3 also has type int * and points to the fourth element of the array. Expression *( a + 3 ) is equivalent to a[3] and yields the value stored in the element.